# accessing a *dll from PHP joomla

Tags: php, dll, joomla

I have a *.dll that controls picture file sizes. It contains a simple function:

```
CopyPic (PChar: inFileName, outFileName: PChar, MaxSize: Int, MaxWidth: int, MaxHeight: int)
```

...and returns an int for error checking.

I need to access it from PHP code. I would it run through Java.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have mixed it all up.

But anyway, take a look at

http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164787

Comment: I found i can make a php Dll that is even better

Answer (score 0):

[Check this out](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.w32api-register-function.php). Never used it but other people have reported success...

**EDIT** You can also probably do it with [.NET](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dotnet.php) and/or [COM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php) although don't ask me how...